# TokenbasedRememberMeServices not working with jdbc-user-service

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

I have implemented a small application which uses spring security and remember me services. It is working fine if I use

```
<authentication-provider>
<user-service/>
//hardcoded the userName/Password here.
```

Even after server restart I am able to access the application without the login.
but when i modifiefd the app-security.xml to use

```
<authentication-provider>
<jdbc-user-service id="userService" data-source-ref="dataSource"        
users-by-username-query="
         query here..."
authorities-by-username-query="
query here..."/>
</authentication-provider>
```

It is not working. Please give more information how can I implement remember me (TokenBaserRememberMeServices
with jdbc-user-service). Any help will be appriciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same username/password in jdbc that you hardcoded ? 
Also have you deleted the token cookie before trying to authenticate using jdbc service  ?

Comment: Yes, I am using same username/password. But I am not deleting the cookie, I can see the cookie in firebug whatever generated before. Is that one is a problem ? Share me any tutorial or link which can help.

Comment: can you try after deleting the cookie ?